# Sex and having a child

Tags: husband-wife, children, intercourse

I am a 25 year old and I have a child who is 6 years old. For a long time me and my husband could not have sex because our child was there we tried everything but it was very had to have sex when he was around and when he was a sleep he used to wake up do to the noise of the bed and other reasons. So my husband and I argue if it’s ok to have sex infront of him when he is awake. Please tell me if it is allowed to have sex when he is awake or around us. Thanks

Comment: I can't comment on whether it is allowed or not, but if you care about your child's mental health, please don't do it in front of him. I remember things from my childhood of 5-6 years period (not things of this nature though), so he will most probably remember it too when he gets older. If it is possible, I would have him sleep in another room in such days/nights, or have a babysitter, or send him to grandparents etc.

Answer (score 2):

The scene of having intercourse in front of a 6 years old will have a negative impact on his mind. He will look at you in a different way. He may one day ask you questions about this when he will grow up. What you can do is you can send him to his grandparent's home  for a few days or ask your husband to take a few days off and then send your boy to somewhere safe(i don't know where you live) and make use of the time-being